# Is it possible to use aliases instead of SQL statements

Tags: sql, sql-server

We all are writing lots of queries everyday and writing a lot of "select, from, group by, etc..".

Let's look at a simple query:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE column1 = 'value'
GROUP BY column2
ORDER BY column2
HAVING count(column2) > 10
```

There are 104 characters above. However, real information is lies under 62 characters above, while 42 characters are just rubbish like "select, where, group by, etc". So, half of my query consists of useless characters.

I'm just get bored writing these again and again. So, is it possible to use alias instead of these statements?
Shortly, I want to write a query like that:

```
S * F table
W column1 = 'value'
G column2
O column2
H count(column2) > 10
```

Is it possible to make it work in SQL?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.  My advice for you, though, is to learn how to touch type.

Comment: No, and for readability (for others) this is a bad idea. But you could use a good DB tool with auto-completion of keywords (and table/column names).

Comment: Maybe you'll find some add-in for SSMS, or you can build it yourself. https://ssmsaddins.codeplex.com/

Comment: Fortunately this is not possible in SQL, which lacks any sort of metaprogramming. You're free to define your own language and have it compile down to SQL, though. That would really let you get down to the nitty-gritty: `table?column1=value^column2!#column>10` is what your query looks like in the language I just invented (and am never going to use again).

Comment: Yes, to save typing a few characters we invent a new cryptic language. Great idea ;-)

Comment: In SQL Server Management Studio you can also use [templates](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/ms179334) if a particular query shape is common, which you can then complete with Ctrl-Shift-M. Personally I've found this far too cumbersome to ever use, but if you're sufficiently clever it might save keystrokes.

Comment: Welcome to SQL. Much of SQL is redundant and required for "readability" - it's right up there with COBOL as a verbose and clumsy language. The answer is "no"; live with it or use something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schwern's answer is on-target. But you don't need to write a parser to reduce the typing of common phrases. You can use macro expansion (in more than one way) to achieve *most* of the same goals.

For example, using [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/AutoHotkey.htm), I can define a substitution like this.

```
::selectstmt::SELECT * FROM table`nWHERE column1 = 'value'`nGROUP BY column2`nORDER BY column2`nHAVING count(column2) > 10
```

Typing `selectstmt` expands to

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE column1 = 'value'
GROUP BY column2
ORDER BY column2
HAVING count(column2) > 10
```

Answer (score 3):

You'd need to write you own parser for your dialect and translate it into real SQL and then think about looking the people trying to read your code later straight in the eye and explain to them why they can't understand your code because you wanted to save 42 characters.

Those 42 characters aren't "rubbish", let's address that idea because it's the real problem here. There's a misconception that programming languages are about talking to computers. They aren't. They're about talking to people.

If computer languages were about talking to computers we'd all be programming in assembly and that would be that. Computer languages exist for the benefit and understanding of the people writing, reading, altering, and otherwise maintaining the code. We say `where` and not `w` for the benefit of the reader (and also to avoid conflicting with other keywords, table, and column names) in the same way that you'd name a column `name` and not `n`.

In addition, SQL is a standard. SQL is a very old and very ubiquitous standard that many people know and are comfortable with. This means they can sit down with your code and have a reasonable chance of figuring out what you're querying. Or if they don't know SQL they can consult any number of tutorials and learning resources.

Once you introduce special snowflake dialects, that's all gone. Now everyone who reads your code must learn your special SQL dialect. You're now responsible for writing all the documentation and learning material for your special dialect and ensuring it's available to people who need to understand your code. By trying to save 42 characters, you've added a lot of work for yourself and everyone reading your code.

You're better off using a SQL builder library for numerous reasons, [Knex.js](http://knexjs.org/) is one example. In addition to smoothing over differences between SQL dialects, it allows you to reused existing statements. Say you wanted to get some stuff from a table...

```
var all_things = knex.select().table('table')
```

Then maybe add a constraint

```
var just_one_thing = all_from_table.where({ column1: 'value' })
```

Then maybe order the results

```
var ordered_things = just_one_thing.orderBy('column2')
```

By adding to existing, and possibly complicated, queries you can greatly reduce the amount of repetitive SQL you need to write.

And also maybe learning to touch type faster.

Comment: "If computer languages were about talking to computers we'd all be programming in assembly and that would be that." While I'm not disputing your central argument, I'd like to point out that "assembly" is not one single programming language, and so there is a real market for using other languages that is not immediately about talking to people: portability by abstracting away from the hardware. It's when you start to get into the *specific way* we abstract away from the hardware that the human aspect comes in -- otherwise we'd all be programming in C and that would be that.

Comment: Ok, I see your concern. However what I want here is not inventing a new language. I don't care about the final output of what I wrote. I just want to write less characters. The thing that I want may be a plugin that converts all "s" to "select". Or any other smart solution.

Comment: @Sab In programming you type less by being smart, not by reducing the number of characters. Follow the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) and build up a library of common queries using a SQL builder that you can then modify as needed. Or consider using an [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) that can write many queries for you.